# String type alternative in C++

Tags: c++

I currently have a function defined in a header that looks like this

```cpp
void foo::GetValue(std::string& str);
```

This function basically assigns a value to `str`. I need to come up with an alternative to `str` (basically, nothing that employs the standard library).

The implementation of the above function is like this in the `.cpp` file:

```cpp
void foo::GetValue(std::string& str)
{
    std::string s = bar.someMethod();
    str = s;
}
```

I want to know what is the best/easiest option for replacing the header?

One approach I had was to replace `std::string` in the header file with `char*` so I would have this in the header:

```cpp
void foo::GetValue(char* str);
```

And in the implementation I would have this:

```
void foo::GetValue(char* str)
{
    std::string resp = bar.someMethod();
    char* c = new char[resp.size() + 1];
    std::copy(resp.begin(), resp.end(), c);
    c[resp.size()] = '\0';
}
```

The problem with the above approach is that a lot of files are calling this function and they will need to modify their code. Also, they will need to free the above memory. Two concerns I have with this is that other callers to this function will need to do the following two things

1. Replace `std::string` being passed to the function with `char*`.
2. Free the `char*` when done using it.

These two items seem very costly to me to trust other callers to do.

Any suggestions on what I can do to solve this problem? Perhaps change the signature to something else? I would prefer if the caller still passes a string, however `string.c_str()` is a constant char pointer.

Comment: The C way is to provide a buffer and a size pair of arguments that you then write to.

Comment: Either use the standard library, or create your own string class. Those are the only two options that don't degrade into "the C way" of doing things.

Comment: Why are you wanting to avoid the Standard Library?

Comment: @sweenish The C++ Standard Library don't work so good in C.

Comment: Note: If you're interfacing with C code and returning allocations with `new` that might be a problem as the C code only has `free()` to deal with that. If the allocations are incompatible you've given them a pointer they can't release. Use `malloc()` if you're intending it to pair up with `free()`.

Comment: @tadman `void foo::GetValue(char* str)` doesn't work in C either...

Comment: @SergeyA That's a valid point, but usually it's re-written as `foo_GetValue(char* str)` or something like that in an `extern "C"` block.

Comment: @tadman absolutely, but I feel the need to mention that as well. Please note, you'd need [opaque] pointer to Foo as well.

Comment: Sorry, on looking over this code again you're returning `std::string` from a `void` function somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given C++ function like this:

```cpp
std::string foo::GetValue(std::string& str)
{
  return bar.someMethod(str);
}
```

Then your equivalent C code looks like this:

```c
void foo_GetValue(char* str, char* res, size_t size)
{
  std::string str_arg = str;
  std::string result = bar.someMethod(str_arg);
  strncpy(res, result.c_str(), size - 1);
  res[size-1] = 0; // Ensure is NUL terminated
}
```

When calling from C:

```c
void example() {
  const BUFFER_LEN = 1024;
  char buffer[BUFFER_LEN];

  foo_GetValue("example", buffer, BUFFER_LEN);
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how the callers will call this function ? why are they passing in a size as well ?

Comment: @Rajeshwar In C it's a convention to supply your own buffer, but as the size of that is unknown unless specified, you must add that as well.

Comment: @tadman can you show me how a caller will call that function ? I have no experience with C so I am a little lost

Comment: @tadman I believe that `char *str` parameter is entirely unused.

Comment: @DrewDormann It was unused in the original, I've force-used it here.

Comment: Added a calling example.

Comment: The function basically will be writing the result to the string passed. The string itself will not have anything. Also there is no str_arg. So I think only one parameter would suffice here which would be `res`. Also wouldnt the calling function need to call `delete*` later ?

Comment: A) You can't `delete` in C, you'd have to `free()`, and B) there's no allocations here, so that's irrelevant.

Comment: You can omit the `str` argument if that's not used.

Comment: When building your `foo_getValue()` as C++ it would also need to be specified as `extern "C"` (which would allow it to be called from C).    There also the option of `foo_getValue()` calling `foo::getValue()` rather than replicating what that function does internally.